# Login to customer account with PrestaShop Webservice API

Tags: javascript, authentication, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm working on integrating PrestaShop with a React application, and I need to authenticate customers and obtain their authentication tokens programmatically.

Is it possible to login to a customer account using the PrestaShop Webservice API and obtain an authentication token? If so, how can I achieve this?

I've been exploring the PrestaShop Webservice API documentation, but I couldn't find a specific endpoint or method to login to a customer account and obtain an authentication token.

My goal is to implement a login functionality in my React application, where customers can enter their credentials, and upon successful login, I can obtain the authentication token to perform authenticated API requests on behalf of the customer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible with the default API. You may consider exploring some of the community projects, for example:
https://www.binshops.com/prestashop-api